# Angular Checkboxes not Binding Properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-controller, angularjs-forms

Having trouble figuring out this problem involving an Angular checkbox form generated from an API.

I can create a checkboxes but two problems:  The checkedness of the boxes does not match the values in what's coming from the API, and when I click the checkboxes the name value changes from its default to "true" or "false."  Have seen other similar questions but can't get this to work. [Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1HGMr7QUpKO1MVCOUUT4?p=preview) and source code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="checkTest">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular Multiple Checkboxes</title>
        <style>
            label {display:block;}
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javaScript">
        var jsonObj = {"fruits":[
            {
              "name": "Apple",
              "desc": "abcdefg",
              "selected": "true",
              "status": "Created"
            },
            {
              "name": "Broccoli",
              "desc": "abcdefg",
              "selected": "true",
              "status": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cucumber",
              "desc": "abcdefg",
              "selected": "false",
              "status": "Created"
            },
            {
              "name": "Daikon",
              "desc": "abcdefg",
              "selected": "false",
              "status": "None"
            }
      ]};
            var fruitsObj = jsonObj.fruits;
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

            <label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fruitSelect" ng-model="fruit.name" ng-value="{{fruit.name}}" ng-checked="fruit.selected"> {{fruit.name}}
            </label>
            <p>Services: {{fruits}}</p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javaScript">

            var app = angular.module('checkTest', []);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.fruits = fruitsObj;
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply the booleans should be `true` or `false` only rather than string `'true'` or `'false'`

Additionally there is not need of `ng-checked` directive. You also need to use `{{index}}` in form field so that it will become an unique element of form like by doing `serviceSelect-{{$index}}`

**Markup**

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="serviceSelect-{{$index}}" 
    ng-model="fruit.selected" 
    ng-value="{{fruit.name}}" />
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkKIDELGwjLvEP6V9ra0?p=preview)

Comment: agreed.  your model should equal fruit.selected and the data true/false should be booleans.

Comment: I think a description of what {{$index}} is doing would improve the answer if you want to edit, but I've figured it out myself.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveKaye Apologize for the same..I forgot to add that description.Updated it..Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox for Angular is true or false. The code should be this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="serviceSelect" ng-model="fruit.selected" ng-value="{{fruit.name}}" ng-checked="fruit.selected">
```